# What does closing a descriptor mean?

Tags: unix, file-descriptor

I thought a descriptor was simply a numerical index in the global file table, so I'm confused by what "close a descriptor" actually means.  Can someone clarify the relationship between processes, descriptors, and open files and explain what it means to open, duplicate, and close descriptors?

Answer (score 0):

A descriptor is a kind of a key. When you want to access some room you need to get the key for it. `open` grants you an access to the room (the file) by giving you a key for it.

To access (`read`/`write`) the room (the file) you need the key.

Then to be fair (the number of key in the system is bounded), when you no more need access to the room you should release the key (`close` the descriptor). Thus, the key is now globally available to other clients...

This is the same for all ressources that a process (a client) want to access. Get a key, use the key, release the key for the ressource. You can have many different sets of keys : keys for files, keys for memory, etc.

The system is the owner of the keys and manage them, process ask system for keys and just use them.

For duplication is just a way to provide key sharing. Two process can use the same key to access the room. If you want to understand what sharing such a key exactly means, you need to understand what an open file exactly is.

In fact, what the system gaves you is not just a simple key as in real life. A descriptor is an entry in a system table that describes the state of a file being manipulated. When you open a file, some data where allocated.

- first in the process own space, there is some data initialized to prepare the process to be able to manipulated a file. These data where placed in the process' descriptors table. Your descriptor is exactly an index in that table. That entry refers to a system open-file table.
- second the system tracks all opened files in its opened-file table. In such a table entry you have many data that helps the system to realize operations you need on the file (which file it is, buffer caching structures, current position to the file, current opening mode, etc).

Now in many cases, there is only one process entry associated to a system entry. But this is not always the case! Think about two different processes writing on the same terminal, then in each process you have an descriptor that represents its access to the terminal (in Unix a terminal is just a file), but both of these entries points to the same system table entry which contains data that says which terminal it is, etc.

`dup`licating a descriptor realize exactly the situation : you have in the same process 2 entries that points the the same system entry. Another way to `dup`licate descriptors is to `fork` a process, that clones a process, and that cloning clones process descriptors table... This is the way two process can share the same terminal for example. A first process (maybe a shell) opens the terminal, and then `fork`s to execute a sub-command such that sub-command can access the same terminal.